# Google Analytics 4 vs Magento Open Source 2.4: GA4 / GTM ecommerce tracking

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.5, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am currently trying to set up ecommerce tracking for GA4 in Magento 2.4.5 (open source). Therefore I have set under *Stores > Configuration > Sales > Google API* at Google *GTag / Google Analytics 4* "Enable" to "Yes" and entered the Measurement-ID. Furthermore, under *Content > Design > Configuration* in the *HTML Head* and *Footer* I have inserted the appropriate Tag Manager Code Snippets.
In the source code I can see that the *"Magento_GoogleGtag/js/google-analytics"* script is included with the correct id, but I can't find any dataLayer.
What else do I need to do to get Magento to output the ecommerce dataLayer definitions?

Comment: GA4 module only sends the purchase data. None of the other events are implemented.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by purchase data, @SohelRana?